# how to add element to immutable array and return that map

Tags: scala, jdbc, mutablemap

```
def jdbcReader(user: String, pwd: String, url: String, id: Int): List[mutable.Map[String, String] = {
   var KeyVal = mutable.Map[String, String]()

   var connection: Connection = null
   try {

      connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pwd)
      val statement = connection.createStatement()
      val resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT Nam, Value FROM tablename WHERE id=?".replace("?", id.toString))
      while (resultSet.next()) {
         val name = resultSet.getString("Nam")
         val value = resultSet.getString("Value")
         // println("name , value = " + name + ", " + value)
      }

   } catch {
      case e => e.printStackTrace()
         val t = e.getMessage()
   }
}
```

How do I add element to list of map and return from this method? I am sure you have already figured I am new to Scala

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what you are trying to add to this List? An empty map?

Comment: trying to add Key & value pair string to map of list

Comment: you have a list of maps not a map of list. I surely don't understand why you are returning a list of Map either. A simple Map suffices here, doesn't it?

Comment: var KeyVal =mutable.Map[String, String]
    var connection:Connection = null
    try {
       val name = resultSet.getString("Nam")
       val value = resultSet.getString("Value")  
        KeyVal += (name -> value)
      }

    } catch {
      case e => e.printStackTrace()
        val t =e.getMessage()

    }
  }

Comment: It keeps throwing type mismatch when i add a element KeyVal += (name -> value)

Comment: what is the type of `resultSet`?

Comment: also change the return type from `List[mutable.Map[String, String]]` to `mutable.Map[String, String]` that would fix your type mismatch issue.

Answer (score 0):

The code has a lot of problems causing clarity issues but I will try to answer your question to the best of my understanding.

```
def jdbcReader(user:String,pwd:String, url: String, id:Int): Map[String, String] ={

   try {

      val connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pwd)
      val statement = connection.createStatement()
      val resultSet = statement.executeQuery(s"SELECT Nam, Value FROM tablename WHERE id=${id.toString}")


      resultSet.map(e => (e.getString("Name"), e.getString("Value")).toMap

       //Or if you want a hashmap
       // resultSet.map(e=>(e.getString("Name"), e.getString("Value")).groupBy(_._1).map { case (k,v) => (k,v.map(_._2))}


   } catch {
     case e : Exception => 
       e.printStackTrace()
       val t = e.getMessage()      
    }
 }
```

We dont' recommend using **var** in Scala. Like ever, unless you really, really have to. So instead of trying to get the results and add them to a map, we will construct a map with these entries on the go.

1) We take the results and map them to a tuple (pair) of key and value

2) Simply call .toMap to turn that into a Map

2.1) You can also do a groupBy, which basically groups all these pairs by key, and later call .map to construct a HashMap

**Note, I will be suggesting some ideas that might be slightly advanced for a new comer, however I highly recommend taking the time to familiarizing yourself with these ideas as they will be of big help to you in the future**

If for any reason you need to update this Map in the future, you should either look into the idea of [function composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition), where you would construct a **new, updated** instance of the Map and pass it to where ever it needs to go through composition. 
Or, in the cases, where absolutely have to maintain a shared state, please look into [State Monads](https://typelevel.org/cats/datatypes/state.html) or [cats.effect.Ref](https://typelevel.org/cats-effect/concurrency/ref.html)

This solution assumes that resultSet is a Collection. However I have to say, I find it very difficult to believe a database operation, just returns. That operation should probably be wrapped in an IO and return a future and the whole thing should return a Either or a Try. We don't like throwing exceptions in Scala either. I will leave those as an exercise to you as these suggestions are outside the scope of the question.